# django forms: could not get manually added(HTML) nested object fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, formset

I am trying to implement django admin like inline addition of related objects in my app. Totally new to django but I am experienced with ROR and Laravel and happen to be good with ajax, so I don't want to go into nested `formsets` from django and want to add related objects form using ajax as I would traditionally do in anywhere else. Just be careful about naming of input fields so you can get them on controller side nicely in an array.

In form.html I am simply adding something like this;

```
<label class="control-label">Name</label>
<input name="items[1][name]" class="form-control"/>
<label class="control-label">Attr</label>
<input name="items[1][attr]" class="form-control"/>
```

This is just an example to give you visual of how my html is generated. I've mutiple items in my form.

Traditional on server side I would get a form object(request input) like this; at-least in Laravel

```
[form=> [
"some_attr"=>"val", 
"items"=> [
   "1"=> [
       "name"=>"some name",
       "attr"=> "some val"
   ]
]
] ]
```

The main point here is that I would get and array of `items` in my request on controller side and can iterate over it.

**PROBLEM**
I am doing everything same as described above but when I am trying to access data from controller side. It doesn't convert items fields to array of objects. 
When I print `form.data`, I get something like this,

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['C5i6Ge7aQMvoMlHODjwgMziXE7RcIs5F99ibo7YsSZnZKF9z2TdMlwhep8OB668M'], 'some_parent_attr': ['value'], 'status': ['1'], 'items[5][name]': ['some name'], 'items[5][attr]': ['some val'] ....
```

Django does not convert items to array it simply makes it a string key like `'items[5][name]'` which cannot be iterated. As I'd have multiple objects with random ids so it is not possible to get all items from this dictionary using there keys.

**Is there a way that I don't know about to get it working? Somehow can be formatted as I expect it to? Or this cannot be done this way?**

I would really appreciate any guidance/help with this problem.

Comment: Write a function to translate the querydict into your custom data structure.

Comment: @HåkenLid and how I would do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Python is returning a querydict, that in certain way is similar to a dictionary, if you want to convert it to a dictionary just add this:

```
myDict = dict(form.data.iterlists())
```

then you can get your elements accessing with the key, example:

```
>>> myDict['items[5][name]'] # Will return
['some name']
```

Comment: This is already possible without converting to dictionary. You can simply get data by key `form.data['items[5][name]']`. This is not what is required. It is not possible to remember keys on server-side. You should read question with little more concentration. And please rectify your answer if possible.

Comment: Or even rename your input with items_name instead of items[1][name] and you will able to iterate

Comment: Why not just add for example `myDict['items[%s][name]' % 5]` iterating with a for loop ?

Comment: Bro, how you are supposed to know that the key will be `5` or anything else. As these are generated randomly on front-end. I hope you have some interaction with add more fields functionality in HTML forms dynamically.

Comment: @tahirwaseer You can create a for loop that add each object found, the problem is that I don't know how bigger could be your numbers, but is much better if you rename the inputs with the same name, it will be automatically grouped in an array

Comment: there is possibility of getting values from dictionary using regex. Because all values start with `items` and then can further be divided into groups by splitting the keys and grouping based on specific `id`.

Comment: But I was looking for some clean way to do this. This same thing would result in itiratable array of objects in Laravel or ROR.